# what is Constants for MD5Transform routine

Tags: md5

i`m trying to understand md5 algorithm
i found code written in c++ here "http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-md5-function"
And it is found all around the internet
and i could not understand what and from where they get these
numbers and why they Constants  in every md5 algorithm
(7,12,17,22,5,....etc)
and could i use Different numbers

```
// Constants for MD5Transform routine.
#define S11 7
#define S12 12
#define S13 17
#define S14 22
#define S21 5
#define S22 9
#define S23 14
#define S24 20
#define S31 4
#define S32 11
#define S33 16
#define S34 23
#define S41 6
#define S42 10
#define S43 15
#define S44 21
```

and search over all the internet and could not find the
Answer

.. Excuse my English is not good

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1321 do not overthink it. md5 is hashing function, so without very complex mathematical background it is impossible to understand meaning of this constants. Hash functions are created by people with PhDs in mathematics and approved after long testing and study by other relay smart people.

Comment: Sometimes these constants are just taken randomly though. [SHA256 uses square roots of the first 8 prime numbers, for example](https://medium.com/biffures/part-5-hashing-with-sha-256-4c2afc191c40)

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20940/how-were-shift-amount-constants-in-md5-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MD5 is is hashing function specify in this [official document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321).

Hashing function are developed by very skilled mathematicians published in scientific papers tested for a very long time before they become industrial standard.

Those constant are arbitrary chosen, but have to meat some complex requirements, so hash functions introduces proper entropy to the result.
If you will modify it most probably you will break this properties make hash function cryptographic weak and you will not able to spot the issue.

Note that md5 nowadays is considered weak and home computer can find collision in reasonable time.

Basically do not overthink it, use only standard solutions (constants).

Answer (score 0):

What about Wikipedia? ;)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Here you can find where such constants come from, and further details about the algorithm.

The reason, in few words, is that MD5 algorithm applies repeatedly some binary functions, using some constants that are part of the algorithm itself, and a non-linear function. Since this is a hashing function, small differences on the original value should generate big differences in the hashed result (the "avalanche effect"). The original algorithm (even if not so strong) respects this assumption, and the algorithm itself defines that, during the hashing, part of the hashed number has to be left-shifted in some (constant) ways, in order to obtain a non-linear function F used in each "round" of the algorithm (to... shuffle the bits even more). Obviously, you can change the "s" (shifting) constants, the K (initialisation) constants, but in this case your algorithm is not the MD5 one, even if you respect the non-linearity assumption regarding the F function (and/or you decide to use different initialisation constants).

I mean, the main point is that MD5 hashing function is made by a procedure that operates shifting numbers, using a non-linear function, and some initialisation values needed to let the procedure work. You can keep the algorithm itself, or change a "and" with a "not", or change the constant values used to hash the input value at each round, or change the number of rounds applied, doing your own version of MD5 algorithm with a different... avalanche size.